# Looking for a program to transfer large files with a "download manager" type of transfer

Tags: windows, ftp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way to transfer 27 GB from a PC to another online?](https://superuser.com/questions/42747/best-way-to-transfer-27-gb-from-a-pc-to-another-online)
>   [How can I send super large files directly to another computer in the Internet for free?](https://superuser.com/questions/211912/how-can-i-send-super-large-files-directly-to-another-computer-in-the-internet-fo)

I'm looking for a Windows program that can transfer large files between two computers over the internet. But I want one that will pick up where it left off of the one of the two sides looses it internet connection for one reason or another. Similar to the way download managers work for browsers. Does anyone know if such a thing exists?

Comment: Yes it does appear to be a duplicate. But its also 2 years old. Maybe there are new methods ti use.

Comment: Also, http://xkcd.com/949/ was just disproved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**BitTorrent.** The latest version of [μTorrent](http://www.utorrent.com/) has a "drop to send" function.

Answer (score 3):

One solution would probably be [DC++](http://dcplusplus.sourceforge.net/).
One of you sets up his machine as a server with the folder with the file shared, gives his address to the other, he connects, downloads, all done.
We used this extensively on LAN Parties in the past, and while not always the fastest it has never failed us.